# Rust borrowing compilation errors

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to learn Rust by writing a simple lexer. Here is what I have so far...

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::str::Chars;

pub struct Lexer<'a> {
    file_name: String,
    file_contents: String,
    iterator: Option<Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {

    fn new(fname: &str) -> Lexer {
        Lexer {
            file_name: fname.to_string(),
            file_contents: String::new(),
            iterator: None,
        }
    }


    // Reads the file contents and creates iterator
    fn init(&'a mut self) { 

        // Open the file
        let mut f = File::open(&self.file_name).expect("Couldn't open file");

        // Read the contents
        f.read_to_string(&mut self.file_contents).expect("Couldn't read file contents");

        self.iterator = Some(self.file_contents.chars());

    }

    // Gets the next character
    fn get_next(&mut self) -> Option<char> {

        self.iterator.unwrap().next()

    }

}

fn main() {

    let mut lexer = Lexer::new("test.txt");
    lexer.init();

    // Assuming the file "text.txt" contains "Hello World" 
    // then the following two lines should print "H" then "e"

    println!("{}", lexer.get_next().unwrap());
    println!("{}", lexer.get_next().unwrap());

}
```

However when I try to compile it I get the following two errors:

```
cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
main.rs:38          self.iterator.unwrap().next()
```

and

```
cannot borrow `lexer` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
main.rs:49      println!("{}", lexer.get_next().unwrap());
```

A Google of the first error reveals that `Clone()`-ing is a possible solution for this kind of error, but I believe this won't work in this case as the iterators state needs to update every time `next()` is called.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to overcome these issues and get it to compile?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you are attempting to [store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423). Unlike other formulations, this *specific* case allows you to "tie the knot" of references, but probably doesn't do what you want. For example, after calling `init`, you will *never* be able to move the `Lexer` because moving it would invalidate the reference.

It also explains the "borrow again" error. Because the lifetime is applied to self, and it's a mutable reference, the lexer itself will keep the mutable reference forever, meaning nothing else can ever mutate it, including itself.

The short answer is: don't organize your code that way. For whatever reason, parsing and lexing is a popular problem in the Rust community. Check out how other libraries do it.

Or check out how iterators work in general. The item being iterated over stays in place, and a separate iterator is returned that references the original item.

Splitting your code into the same two pieces will likely be the best direction.

Comment: Well, I got half of it. I have the kettle boiling now to make a coffee. Next time I'll have my coffee before answering, hah.